# How do I extinguish blue fire?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

There's blue fire all around this chest. No amount of Isaac's salty tears will extinguish the blue fire. How do I put out the blue fire?

[image: Blue fire]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bombs (or any other ability that would destroy rocks, like mom's foot) seems to extinguish them. They have an added bonus of a chance to drop a soul heart for each blue flame extinguished.